# resolve() function is returning undefined in a promise

Tags: node.js, express, promise, youtube-dl

I am converting youtube-dl npm package to have promise instead of callbacks so I have working function but its not resolving the resolve function am I missing something here?
my youtube downloader function looks like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');


const downloadVideoAsync = (url) => {
    const video = youtubedl(url,['--format=18'],{ cwd: __dirname }); 
     if( video !== null) {
         video.on('info', function(info) {
             console.log('Download started');
             console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
             console.log('size: ' + info.size);
             const videoName = info.fulltitle.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
             if(videoName) {

                 return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                     video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`videos/${videoName}.mp4`));
                     video.on('end', function() {
                        console.log(`this is the videoName in async ${videoName}`);
                        resolve(true);
                     })



                 });
             }

         });
     }

}

module.exports.downloadVideoAsync = downloadVideoAsync;
```

And I am calling that function in main server.js file like this :

```
 const asdf = async () => {
      const result = await downloadVideoAsync('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsceiAe1B6w');
      console.log(`this is the result ${result}`);
  }

  asdf();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `undefined` because that's what `downloadVideoAsync` is returning.

```
  console.log(
      typeof downloadVideoAsync('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsceiAe1B6w')
  ); // undefined
```

For your code to work like you want, you should wrap the `video.on('info'` with a Promise.

```
const downloadVideoAsync = (url) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const video = youtubedl(url,['--format=18'],{ cwd: __dirname }); 
        if(!video)
            return reject(new Error('Video is empty...'));

         video.on('error', reject);

         video.on('info', function(info) {
             console.log('Download started');
             console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
             console.log('size: ' + info.size);
             const videoName = info.fulltitle.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
             if(!videoName)
                  return reject(new Error('Empty name'));

             video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`videos/${videoName}.mp4`));
             video.on('end', function() {
                  console.log(`this is the videoName in async ${videoName}`);
                  resolve(true);
             });


         });

    });
}
```

Now, `downloadVideoAsync` returns a `Promise`, instead of `undefined`, and it will wait until `end` is called before resolving, or it will reject if the video is empty.

Comment: what about reject() where can i call it can you please add that also to your answer. Thanks

Comment: I already added that, when the video is null or on `video.on('error')`